# Promise plus number returns promise

Tags: javascript, promise, type-conversion

I have a simple code

```js
async function foo() {
  const b = bar()
  return 2 + b
}

async function bar() {
  return 2
}

(async() => {
  console.log(typeof foo())
})()
```

and it logs `object`. Not `NaN`. How does it happen that `number + object` -> `object`?

From what I remember from `+` spec if one of the operands is a primitive and second is an object then object should be converted to primitive. In this case with `.valueOf()` method

Comment: It concats the two values as "2[object Promise]". Just leave out the typeof

Comment: `foo` is an `async function`, and calling it (`foo()`) will return a promise which clearly is an object.

Comment: Think "type of thing" vs "type of what thing returns" you get the first in this context.  A road is still a road no matter if you haul beer or fruit in the truck on it or just walk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think it's because `async` functions are not resolved yet in your case, becaue there is no `await`. So you are getting promise objects instead of your result.

see these cases:

```js
async function foo () {
    const b = await bar() //await result
    return 2 + b
}

async function bar () {
    return 2
}

;(async () => {
    console.log(typeof await foo()) //number
})()
```

```js
async function foo () {
    const b = bar() //no await
    return 2 + b
}

async function bar () {
    return 2
}

;(async () => {
    console.log(typeof await foo()) //string
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions `foo` and `bar` return a promise, so, you're getting the type of promise (Object)

**Probably you want to compare the result, so you need to wait for promise resolves the concatenation:**

```
let result = await foo();
             ^
```

```js
async function foo() {
  const b = bar() // Here you need to wait as well.
  return 2 + b; // 2 + "[object Promise]"
}

async function bar() {
  return 2
}

(async() => {
  let result = await foo();
  console.log(result);
  console.log(typeof result);
})()
```

**Now, to get the NaN value you need to convert to number:**

```js
async function foo() {
  const b = bar();  // Here you need to wait as well.
  return Number(2 + b); // <- Try to conver to number
}

async function bar() {
  return 2
}

(async() => {
  let result = await foo();
  console.log(result);
  console.log(typeof result);
})()
```